# Getting error With foreach loop when data not found

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am geting This Arry when there is no result set:

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [res] => 
        )

)
```

I am geting This Arry when there is  result set:

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [res] => 1
            [rows] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [aprtid] => 11
                            [bldcode] => a
                            [buldname] => cd 
                            [aptno] => 901
                            [aptcore] => 2
                            [aptfloor] => 2
                            [buldsiteid] => 11
                            [rsdntname] => Gaurav
                            [rsdntemail] => Gaurav@gmail.com
                            [rsdntphone] => 9891110987
                            [rsdntpic] => 1498461013.jpg
                            [accessperson] => Ankit
                        )

After that i did this to recieved data :

  <?php
    $value=$data['rows'];

    ?>
its giving me that array 

    Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object

            (
                [aprtid] => 11
                [bldcode] => A_12
                [buldname] => BT Tower 
                [aptno] => 901
                [aptcore] => 2
                [aptfloor] => 2
                [buldsiteid] => 11
                [rsdntname] => Pankaj
                [rsdntemail] => pankaj@gmail.com
                [rsdntphone] => 9876543219
                [rsdntpic] => 
                [accessperson] => Ankit
            )


for accessing this data i used foreach cos there can be multiple records so i used that.

    <?php

    foreach ($value as $data) {
    ?>
    <tr>
     <td> <img src='<?=BASE_URL?>assets/images/<?= (!empty($data->rsdntpic)) ? $data->rsdntpic : '' ?>'> </td> 
    <td> <?= (!empty($data->name)) ? $data->name : 'No Records' ?> </td>
    <td> <?=(!empty($data->email)) ? $data->email : 'No Records' ?></td>
    <td> <?= (!empty($data->phone)) ? $data->phone : 'No Records' ?> </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
```

> My question is that when i am recieving the data its working gud and
>   fine but rows not in the array as i show you above its giving me alot
>   of errors like 
>       Severity: Notice
>       Message: Undefined index: rows
>
> ```
> OR 
>
> Severity: Warning
> Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
> ```

Comment: Have you tried to pass **$data['rows']** in foreach loop ?

Comment: use `isset()` to check if the value exist or not before iterating over your data as `isset($data['rows'])`

Comment: can u update my question ??

Comment: @ B2725  i did but getting same error

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use php `isset()` to check if the `value is set and not null` before iterating over your data as `isset($data['rows'])`

```
<?php

    if(isset($data['rows'])) {
        $value=$data['rows'];
        foreach ($value as $data) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td> <img src='<?=BASE_URL?>assets/images/<?= (!empty($data->rsdntpic)) ? $data->rsdntpic : '' ?>'> </td> 
        <td> <?= (!empty($data->name)) ? $data->name : 'No Records' ?> </td>
        <td> <?=(!empty($data->email)) ? $data->email : 'No Records' ?></td>
        <td> <?= (!empty($data->phone)) ? $data->phone : 'No Records' ?> </td>
    </tr>
<?php }} ?>
```

Comment: Don't we need a `if()` with isset in php now!!

Answer (score 0):

Use empty function to check whether array has values or not.

```
<?php
if (!empty($data['rows'])) {
}

?>
```